# Getting selected item from listview

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented list view in android using custom adapter. In each there is two or more fields . i want to get specific field on which click is made. how will it possible ?any help appreciated.

Comment: **In each there is two or more fields.** fields means TextViews or other Views? If yes then implement **onClickListener** to that field in `getView()` of **CustomAdapter**..

Comment: Yes. there is two or more TextView.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
 setOnItemClickListener
```

on the listView. e.g

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

                //"Here you will get the position on which you have clicked"
// and if you want the item at that position you have to **adapter.getItem(position)**
            }



    });
```

see if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
     lstvw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                          String selectedFromList =   (String) lstvw.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt);

                          System.out.println("array:> > >  > > > >========================>"+selectedFromList);
                      }

                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implemet implements OnItemClickListener and override onItemClick method. override onItemClick method like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    yourList.get(position);//This will give you object on specfic pisition clicked
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), classToCallOnClick.class);
    .  
              .  
              .  
              .
}
```

Hope this will help you.....